# Why did Fastlane upload the internal used by the. aab script track to the production track after a successful upload

Tags: java, android

1.The script is as follows.
lane :upload_to_play_store do
aab_file_path = Dir["*.aab"].first
upload_to_play_store(
aab: "./app-release.aab",
track: 'internal',
skip_upload_apk: true
)
end
2.Results uploaded to Google Play.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcbDV.png)

Hope to upload to the internal track of Google Play normally.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.